# Struggle with Hilbert Space inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Here we have $\mathcal{H}$ a Hilbert space with $\{x_n\} \subseteq \mathcal{H}$, $x \in \mathcal{H}$ with $\|x\|=1$, and $\{a_n\}$ a sequence of complex numbers.  In helping me with a problem, my professor suggested the following inequalities:
$$
\left| \langle x, \sum_{n=1}^N a_n x_n \rangle \right| \leq \sum_{n=1}^N |a_n \langle x, x_n \rangle |
\leq \left( \sum_{n=1}^N |a_n|^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \sum_{n=1}^N | \langle x,x_n \rangle|^2 \right)^{1/2}.
$$

I have two questions:

1. After the first inequality, shouldn't the complex coefficients now be their conjugates?
2. I'm really struggling to understand the second inequality.  It feels like some use of Holder's inequality, but with the summation I don't see how that applies either.

Ultimately I desire clarity on the second inequality: if true it seems really useful!

Comment: $|\langle x,a_n x_n\rangle |=|\overline{a_n}\langle a,x_n\rangle|=|a_n||\langle x,x_n\rangle|=|a_n\langle x,x_n\rangle|$.  as for the second equality, it is just Cauchy-chwarts applied to $\mathbb{R}^N$, $\sum^N_{n=1}|a_n||\langle x,x_n\rangle|\leq \Big(\sum^N_{n=1}|a_n|^2\Big)^{1/2}\Big(\sum^N_{n=1}|\langle x,x_n\rangle|^2\Big)^{1/2}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first question, if you consider the product $\langle.,.\rangle$ to be linear in the first and conjugate ilnear in the second factor You would have
$$\langle x,\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_nx_n\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\overline{a_n}\langle x,x_n\rangle$$ but of course You have $|a_n\langle x, x_n\rangle|=|\overline{a_n}\langle x, x_n\rangle|$.The second inequality is that of [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) with the vectors $(|a_n|)_{n=1}^N$ and $(|\langle x,x_n\rangle|)_{n=1}^N$

Answer (score 4):

For your first question: yes, but $|a_n \langle x, x_n \rangle|$ is the same as $|\bar{a_n} \langle x, x_n \rangle|$.

For the second: this is an application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (which is a special case of Holder's inequality). In this case it is actually Cauchy-Schwarz on $\mathbb{R}^N$, not on $\mathcal{H}$; let $r_n = |a_n|$ and $s_n = |\langle x, x_n\rangle|$. These are real $N$-tuples and thus
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^N |r_n s_n| \leq \left(\sum_{n = 1}^N |r_n|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n = 1}^N |s_n|^2\right)^{1/2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I had never used Cauchy-Schwarz in this context.  Both answers helped me, but he answered 1 second earlier than you.  Thanks again.